# WYSIWYG editor on mobile version

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, editor

Can you implement WYSIWYG editor in the mobile version of Stack Overflow? I'm kinda often use the site from my iPhone and it would be nice not to enter `*`s and `` ` ``s manually. :)